# Windows Store JMA Feature Verification

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-store

I'm sorry for my bad English. Recently I have posted a windows 10 uwp application. In the report I have received from Microsoft, it has some issue called "JMA Feature Verification", which lists some feature (like live tiles, notifications and etc.) that my application doesn't need. For some reason, it must be no entries in the issue list. Would it be possible that I do something to solve the issue without adding features?

Part of the issues in report:

[image: part of the issues in report]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of a service agreement, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMA is a private agreement between a publisher/developer and Microsoft. So I guess you've signed such agreement where you commit to implement the five features listed (adaptive layout, live tiles etc). I suggest you to ask support from your local Microsoft point of contact.